# Counting the number of matches between multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to count the number of matches between multiple columns.

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 999 | 100 | 500 |
| 999 | 100 | 123 | 999 |
| 100 | 999 | 999 | 500 |

I want a formula to count how many values there are that occur in every column. So it should return 1 in this example as only 999 occurs in the columns A, B, C, D. I also need to modify the formula so it only checks how many values there are that occurs in all three column A, B and C. So in this example it would be 2 as 100 and 999 occurs in the columns A, B and C.

I am trying to find and answer but I cannot. The only formula I found is for compering two columns

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(COUNTIF(A2:A5,B2:B5)))
```

but I am not able to modify it so it works fine for three or four columns. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=let(Σ,filter(A2:D,A1:D1), Λ,unique(tocol(Σ,1)),
     countif(map(Λ,lambda(x,sum(bycol(Σ,lambda(y,ifna(xmatch(x,y)^0)))))),columns(Σ)))
```

[image]

- *used `row_1 checkboxes` to select which columns needs to be taken into account*

Comment: I have no clue how the formula works but it is all I needed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of unique numbers from the range using [`UNIQUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10522653?hl=en)-[`TOCOL`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187258?hl=en) and count how many times they occur in each column using [`BYCOL`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12571032?hl=en).

```cpp
=LET(r,A2:D,SUMPRODUCT(MAP(UNIQUE(TOCOL(r,1)),LAMBDA(val,COLUMNS(r)=SUM(N(0<BYCOL(r,LAMBDA(c,COUNTIF(c,val)))))))))
```

[image]